# «Позвонить в 02» или «позвонить 02»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Подскажите, будьте добры, *позвонить **в** 02* или *позвонить 02*?

Comment: Анастасия, вы задали столько вопросов - и не приняли ни одного ответа.)))

Comment: Всё-таки 2 ответа были приняты.

Answer (score 2):

***Позвонить 02.***

Что такое "в 02"?

(+)----

Заставили меня таки объясниться. 
Идеальным можно считать вариант "позвонить по номеру 02".

> Вопрос № 216619
>   Добрый день! Возник спор с коллегами, как все-таки правильно
>   говорить/писать: "позвонить по номеру" или "позвонить на номер"?
>   Спасибо за ответ!
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Лучше: *позвонить по номеру*.

("Грамота").

В других ответах рассматриваются и варианты "на номер", но "по номеру" никто не оспаривает. Но автор и спрашивает не об этом

Теперь что до вариантов без слова "номер" и подобных.
"Позвонить 02" - такая форма была практически единственной некоторое время назад. На всех подъездах висел плакатик "при пожаре звонить 01".

Сейчас он упростился, но тоже есть почти во всех подъездах

[image: При пожаре]

> Откройте телефонную книгу. О пожаре звонить ― 01. В милицию ― 02. 
>   В скорую помощь ― 03.

[Феликс Кривин. Хвост павлина (1981-1987)]

> Члены экипажей одеты соответственно ― в цилиндрах, во фраках, в
>   клетчатых жилетках, дамы в длинных платьях и кокетливых шляпках… Вдруг
>   раздался вой пожарной сирены ― это на площадку лихо въехал
>   ярко-красный пожарный « ГАЗ-АА» 1936 года, с дребезжащим ведром на
>   конце длинной деревянной лестницы и с плакатом « При пожаре звонить
>   01». Бородатые пожарники в брезентовых робах и старинных касках с
>   гребнями, напоминающими шлемы римских воинов… Короче, все вокруг было
>   выдержано в стиле « ретро».

[Наталья Тодорова. Гонки в стиле «ретро» «Юность», 1976]

Здесь "по 02" неуместно.

Авторитетных примеров типа "позвони **на** 02" не имею, считаю грубым нарушением стилистики. 
Думаю, с авторами сыграло злую шутку непонимание различий между "позвони на номер" (тоже не лучший выбор, но уже привыкли), и "позвони на 02". Последнее - чудовищно.

Comment: 02 — полиция. А что такое позвонить 02? Позвонить 88005553535 — это как?

Comment: @Aer "позвонить 02" - это набрать номер 02. А "в 02"-то как?!

Answer (score 0):

Позвонить на (номер) 02.

Примеры из книг:

*Не дозвонится на городской номер, будет звонить на мобильник, будет звонить в кабинет на служебный телефон, будет звонить дежурному по прокуратуре, всех достанет и меня найдет.*

*Городские власти также отправили письма всем собственникам телефонов-автоматов с информацией о том, что они обязаны разрешать детям бесплатно звонить на номер 1098 в любое время суток.*

*То есть если какой-нибудь мужчина захочет погулять, то скажет жене, что его телефон не работает, и попросит звонить на номер «друга».*

*Снова пытается звонить на номер Рушана — раз в три минуты с самого утра.*

"В 02" - это разговорный вариант:

*Позвонить в (службу по номеру) 02.*

Comment: "Звонить на номер" - грубая стилистическая ошибка. На номер можно отправить смс. Звонить - 02. Просто.

Comment: С чего вы это взяли? "Позвонить 02" - так вообще не говорят.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+02%22 А вы с чего взязи?

Comment: Добавил в ответ примеры из книг.

Comment: Не лучшие примеры, прямо скажем. И без ссылок. Но я имел в виду даже не это. Номер - цифрами. Вы же это предлагали, нет?!

Comment: То есть "позвонить 88005553535" корректно? Так не говорят. "Набрать" - да, но не "звонить".

Comment: Не выдумывайте, я вам ссылку дал.

Comment: Я про все номера ("позвонить 88005553535" - кто так скажет?). Следовательно, для двухзначных номеров это звучит тоже странно, хоть и не настолько. Да и "звонить 02" (что на плакате) ещё как-то звучит, но "позвонить 02" - нет.